# how to add margin in header left or header right in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header

I am trying to do a Twitter clone to practice. I need to add some margin to the image on the left and the icon in right. This is the header right now.

[image: photo]

The code I tried:

```js
<BottomTab.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={TabOneScreen}
  options={({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<"TabOne">) => ({
    headerRightContainerStyle: {
      marginRight: 10,
    },
    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="md-home" color={color} />,
    headerTitle: () => (
      <TabBarIcon name={"logo-twitter"} size={30} color={Colors.light.tint} />
    ),
    headerRight: () => (
      <MaterialCommunityIcons
        name={"star-four-points-outline"}
        size={30}
        color={Colors.light.tint}
      />
    ),
    headerLeft: () => (
      <ProfilePicture
        size={40}
        image={
          "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1431295293564280838/25cTnq7B_400x400.jpg"
        }
      />
    ),
  })}
/>
```

It doesn't give an error but it doesn't add margin too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried any of the following

- Adding the margin to the components instead of the container
- Using `paddingRight` instead of `marginRight` in the `headerRightContainerStyle`

Sometimes adding margins to containers that use flexbox (all components in the case of react native) causes bugs and inconsistencies that can be avoided by using padding instead